# How to escape the Unicode Character &#160;

Tags: c#, html, regex, markup

I am trying to escape markups and unicode charcaters from the string using the Regular expression like below

```
string b = Regex.Replace(StNameTag, "<[^>]+>|\u200B|\n|\t|\r", string.Empty);
```

But the issue is its not escape some characters like `&#160;` and some string even has

`ED5D6EB4918943C197E874EF6414E351 .ExternalClass p.MsoNormal, ED5D6EB4918943C197E874EF6414E351 .ExternalClass li.MsoNormal, ED5D6EB4918943C197E874EF6414E351 .ExternalClass div.MsoNormal {margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:8.0pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:107%;font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}ED5D6EB4918943C197E874EF6414E351 .ExternalClass .MsoChpDefault {font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}ED5D6EB4918943C197E874EF6414E351 .ExternalClass .MsoPapDefault {margin-bottom:8.0pt;line-height:107%;}ED5D6EB4918943C197E874EF6414E351 .ExternalClass div.WordSection1 {}&#160;ABCD`

I will need only ABCD from the above string. How can I escape them.

Comment: Why not match any whitespace using `\s`? Use `@"<[^>]+>|[\u200B\s]"`. You may certainly just add `\u00A0` as an alternative that is a `NO-BREAK SPACE` char to your current regex. Or `&#160;` if it is just a literal substring.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I used `<[^>]+>|\u200B|\n|\t|\r|\u00A0` but I stil see `&#160;`

Comment: `&#160;` is an entity that when rendered is the `\u00A0` Unicode character. Also, strings in C# have to be escaped like this `"<[^>]+>|\\u200B|\\n|\\t|\\r|\\u00A0"` or a _verbatim_  string like this `@"<[^>]+>|\u200B|\n|\t|\r|\u00A0"`

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/388741). It looks like you are trying to manipulate HTML using Regular expressions, which is a [regularly occurring source of questions here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252396/regex-and-html-the-long-tail-annoys-me). For example, see [this question, and its accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/). So if I'm right, do yourself a favour, and use an HTML parser (and try to avoid the XY problem).